# NullPointerException Error on simple program

Tags: java

I am trying to make a basic game in which a dot is moved randomly around the screen, and when it is clicked, the user gets some points. When I run the program, I get a NullPointerException at the start method. I am wondering what I am doing wrong as well as any types for improving the program. Thank you!

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.stage.Popup;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public class CatchTheDot extends Application{

//create ball for game
public static Circle dot;

//create pane to run game
public static Pane window;

//create score counter
int score = 0;

//creat random
Random random = new Random();

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    window.getChildren().add(dot);

    // create scene and place on pane
    Scene s = new Scene(window, 800, 800);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Catch The Dot");
    primaryStage.setScene(s);
    primaryStage.show();

    //move dot
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() 
        {
        @Override
        public void run(){
        window.getChildren().remove(dot);
        int ranX = random.nextInt(800-1); // random value from 0 to width
        int ranY = random.nextInt(800-1);  // random value from 0 to height
        window.getChildren().add(ranY, dot);
        }
        }, 0, 5000);        


    // create listener
    dot.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
        {
        public void handle(MouseEvent e){
        if(e.getSource()==dot)
        {
            score = score + 10;
            if(score == 50)
            {
                popUp(primaryStage);
            }
        }
    }
});
}
public void popUp(final Stage primaryStage)
{
    primaryStage.setTitle("You won!");
    final Popup popup = new Popup();
    popup.setX(300);
    popup.setY(200);
    Text t = new Text("You won! Nice job!");
    Text tt = new Text("Play again?");
    Button yes = new Button("yes");
    Button no = new Button("no");
    popup.getContent().addAll(t, tt, yes, no);
    yes.setOnAction(e -> Yes());
    no.setOnAction(e -> No());
}

public void Yes()
{
    restartGame();
}
public void No()
{
    System.exit(0);
}
public void restartGame()
{
    score = 0;
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Error log:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$156(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at CatchTheDot.start(CatchTheDot.java:34)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$163(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Exception running application CatchTheDot
```

Comment: Call you paste the error log?

Comment: In which line are you getting the error?

Comment: Can you not use a debugger?

Comment: The likely cause is that `dot` is never instantiated, but as others point out, you would be better served by doing some basic debugging.

Comment: I don't see your `window` variable initialized anywhere, and you're calling its method

Comment: Wow this blew up quick, I will add the error log right now

Comment: `window.getChildren().add(dot);`... Both `window` and `dot` seem to be null there.

Comment: Please do not use PasteBin. You will get warnings when you approach the max content length of a question.

Comment: Sorry, was having trouble formatting @cricket_007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 34, as the trace says:

`window.getChildren().add(dot);`

either `window` or `dot` (or both) are not initialized by then. Hence the null pointer exception.

Comment: Am I not initializing them at the beginning of the code? I thought that is what I was doing....

Comment: You are declaring them, in that you are telling the compiler that a specific variable should be treated as an object of a specific class. You never initialized it.

Comment: Declaring a variable specifies its type, to initialize it, you need to assign any value to them. How can the compiler evaluate an expression with this variable if it doesn't know its value?

Comment: Ok I understand what are saying, for some reason I thought both was happening all ready.. Thank you both for your help

Comment: Great. Consider accepting one of the answers if your problem is solved.

Comment: He can't. Marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

`Window` and `Dot` have been declared but not defined

Comment: How do I define them? Sorry if this is a stupid question...